# Pointer to trait

Tags: pointers, rust, traits, ffi

When I started learning Rust, I naively assumed Rust's pointers to traits were implemented just like a C++ pointer to a base class, and wrote some code that worked even under that assumption. Specifically, the code I wrote interfaced with an FFI library that needed to read and seek a stream, and it was something like this:

```
struct StreamParts {
    reader: *mut Read,
    seeker: *mut Seek,
}

fn new_ffi_object<T: Read + Seek + 'static>(stream: T) -> FFIObject {
    let stream_ptr   = Box::into_raw(Box::new(stream));
    let stream_parts = Box::into_raw(Box::new(StreamParts {
        reader: stream_ptr as *mut Read,
        seeker: stream_ptr as *mut Seek,
    }));

    ffi_library::new_object(stream_parts, ffi_read, ffi_seek, ffi_close)
}

extern "C" fn ffi_read(stream_parts: *mut StreamParts, ...) -> c_ulong {
    (*stream_parts.reader).read(...)
    ...
}

extern "C" fn ffi_seek(stream_parts: *mut StreamParts, ...) -> c_ulong {
    (*stream_parts.seeker).seek(...)
    ...
}

extern "C" fn ffi_close(stream_parts: *mut StreamParts) {
    mem::drop(Box::from_raw(stream_parts.reader));
    mem::drop(Box::from_raw(stream_parts));
}
```

And it worked. However, there are three things I don't fully understand about why it works:

1. Rust's trait objects are fat, containing two pointers. Thus, unlike C++, `*mut Read` is a pointer to a trait object, correct? And where is this trait object allocated? The Rust docs don't touch on this specific case.
2. Am I correct to assume that `mem::drop(Box::from_raw(stream_parts.reader))` fully drops the original stream?
3. Why is the `'static` needed in `new_ffi_object()`?

Comment: Interesting question; I know that Rust references are fat, but I don't know whether pointers are (I assume they have to be?).

Comment: [One question per question, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829). Think about when you were searching for answers to these questions (**you did search, right?**). Would *you* have clicked on a question titled "pointer to trait" for any of these bullet points? SO isn't about answering *your* question, it's about building a world-class knowledge base for **everyone** to refer to in the future. I guarantee if you had asked questions separately, at least one of them would have been answered already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers and references behave exactly the same, except for the borrow-checker which forbids you to have dangling references and the fact that you need to wrap pointer dereferencing into an `unsafe` block.

1. So yes, `sizeof::<*mut Read>() == sizeof::<*mut ()>() * 2`. The trait object isn't allocated anywhere. It's nothing more than a struct with two fields. One that is a pointer that points to your data, and one that is a pointer that points to the vtable. The vtable is allocated in the static memory.
2. Correct. It accesses the vtable pointer of `reader` and looks up the `drop` impl in the vtable.
3. If you didn't have a `'static` lifetime, your `T` might contain references with lifetimes shorter than `'static`. All that lifetime bound says is that `T` doesn't have such references and may thus be copied anywhere without restrictions, even on the heap.